# Is there a good weapon for Aligern?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

I've had Aligern in my party for a while now and he doesn't seem very useful to me, which I think is because of his weapon skill.

Aligern is trained in medium weapons and has inability with all other weapon types, he also is unable to learn speed. I.e. you can neither improve his speed edge nor his speed stat pool.

Yet, the vast majority of medium weapons I found are speed based, the only non-speed based ones I can think of are his starting mace and the battleaxe, both very weak weapons.

This leaves me with the options of either

- use a good medium weapon, which doesn't appear to be a good choice, because his speed stat is so bad
- use a low quality medium weapon, which is bad, as he uses a 7 dmg weapon, while others have 15+ dmg weapons
- use a heavy weapon and just cope with the massive to-hit penalty.

Which option is best? Is there a good might or intellect based medium weapon in the game? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: Judging from what the Wiki says, isn't Aligern a caster? shouldn't you give him a long-range weapon and let him cast from behind the ranks? or does Torment not have long-range weapons?

Comment: @Nzall Aligern has good might and intellect statistics, so he is suited for both. Besides weapons are classified as light, medium and heavy. There are melee and ranged weapons in each of those categories. So yes, a ranged weapon is certainly an option, too. But it needs to be might or intellect based and I've only found speed based ones.

Comment: Aligern is a Nano, which AFAIK is the wizard equivalent of Numenera. You're not really supposed to have those use their weapons all that often, and their weapons are more intended as a backup in case they are somehow unable to use their spells.

Comment: @Nzall Aligern doesn't start with an offensive spell, so he must use weapons early on. I also don't think I even had the option of learning offensive spells on reaching tier 2, not 100% sure about that, but I think I would have taken one, if I had. The types don't really force a character into anything. Aligern has training in medium weapons i.e. +15% to attacks with those, that's something a normal nano cannot even get. If your main character is a nano, you only get novice in light weapons with inability in medium and heavy. Aligern is certainly meant to use weapons.

Comment: @Nzall Dulkan is right, Aligern is a battle mage (it's stated explicitly in the game), so he's proficient with medium weapons and close combat, while having high Endurance and Might pools. As such, he's actually intended to be a tank fighter/healer/buffer hybrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr don't bother with Medium Might weapons for Aligern after Sagus Cliffs - use Heavy Might or Light Intellect weapons instead

Sadly, T:ToN is awfully unbalanced in this aspect; most of the good weapons are either Speed-based or Heavy & 2-H. Thus, with Aligern, you can take one of three possible roads:

1. (not recommended) use Aligern as a mixed mage/fighter, and stick strictly to *Medium*/*Might* weapons - that'll leave you with [Battleaxe](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Battleaxe) bought ASAP in Circus Minor (7+2*3=13 damage with 3 Effort+Edge) for the majority of the game, and with [Temporal Hammer](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Temporal_Hammer) (16+2*6=28 with 6 Effort+Edge) in the game's ending. That, as you have already noticed, will make him really lacking in the midgame. Sadly, there simply ain't anything better available in this category (see 3. for possible solutions).
2. (not recommended) use Aligern as a support healer/buffer/damage tank only, ignoring the fact he's a *battle* nano at all. This will make the damage output of the team very low, making the fights long and tedious, especially if you have Rhin in your party.
3. (recommended) use Aligern as a mixed mage/fighter, get him 4 Might Edge and put all Pool into Intellect, and *ignore* his Medium Weapons preference, while respecting him as a Might/Intellect hybrid. Since he's severely penalised in Speed (both in terms of Pool and of Edge), you'd either have to use 2-H (no shield!) Heavy Might weapons (i.e. in rough order of appearance, [Quickice Axe](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Quickice_Axe), [Runic Blade of Tol Danor](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Runic_Blade_of_Tol_Danor) & [Galvanic Hammer](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Galvanic_Hammer)) - you'll get the penalty for Heavy Weapons, but with 4 Might Edge, a decent Might Pool and Aligern's *Combat Magus*, you'll easily get to 100% to-hit - *and/or* Light Intellect weapons: [Whispers](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Whispers) and, later, [Ecstasy Paralyzer](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Ecstasy_Paralyzer); don't invest into Intellect Edge, since the Intellect weapons suck in endgame - your Intellect Pool should be enough, giving you a nice bonus to Willpower in the meantime. That'll get you into 20-ish damage bracket easily, *not including* the bonuses from Artifacts, Tattoos and, possibly, [Eyes of the Finite](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Eyes_of_the_Finite) - which can drag you into 30-ish and beyond. In the endgame, switch to Temporal Hammer, and be happy with your very own Battle Mage<sup>TM</sup> kicking asses all around.

Answer (score 2):

First of all Aligern has an unique "[Living tattoos](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Living_Tattoos)" skill that makes him better on repetitive actions - each consecutive heal/damage/cast will be better than the last one in chain. This makes him a very good tank/healer (especially if you take in consideration his later skills) because you can either make him soak (and heal himself) the damage or simply keep healing your party members, but indeed not a very good damage dealer, that is unless you make him focused ONLY on combat (using any other type of action would negate the Living Tattoos bonus).

Example of useful medium weapon that uses Might instead of Speed is the Battleaxe:[image]

That you can find at vendor at Circus or at the the trader Tantalum in the Valley of Dead Heroes. Nothing fancy, but it is available early and it would cover the low Speed stat that he would have to toherwise use.

Comment: He actually currently has the healing sword, but it is speed based. With 30-40% hit chance it is pretty useless. The big problem is, that he only has a speed pool of 2, which cannot be improved. So essentially you can get off one decent attack with that weapon and that's it. Combat also usually doesn't last long enough for living tattoos to have a massive effect. As a healer is a good idea, though I barred myself from that by not improving his healing skill and using Rhin as my healer.

Comment: Well then probably the best solution would be replacing him - Calistene would work good as a ranged damage, Erritis or Matkina are great at melee

Comment: It isn't possible to replace him, once you've reached the valley of dead heroes. Currently I gave him a light intellect based weapon and he works better with that. He also tiered up to 3 and he cannot learn any damage spells. It seems weird to me, that they give him aptiude in medium weapons, but add no medium weapons to the game, which he can use effectively.

Comment: can't you use the bronze sphere to summon other companions? Sorry, i hvane't been that far in game yet.

Comment: Didn't even know the bronze sphere has a use. So, I could replace him if needed. Still, the question of whether there is a good weapon for him, i.e. a medium weapon, which is might or intellect based and does damage comparable to the healing sword still stands.